# Why browser does not see local storage elements' values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, browser

I am creating a simple Tetris game using React JS. My main  Component besides App.js is a Tetris.js functional component. In useEffect() I am storing components like the stage or current player tetromino using Local Storage. While playing, retrieving data in the console is possible and the data is not null.

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("dropTimeStored", JSON.stringify(dropTime));
    localStorage.setItem("stageStored", JSON.stringify(stage));
    localStorage.setItem("playerStored", JSON.stringify(stage));
    localStorage.setItem("rowsClearedStored", JSON.stringify(rowsCleared));
    localStorage.setItem("scoreStored", JSON.stringify(score));
    localStorage.setItem("rowsStored", JSON.stringify(rows));
    localStorage.setItem("levelStored", JSON.stringify(level));
    localStorage.setItem("gameOverStored", JSON.stringify(gameOver));
}, [dropTime, stage, player, rowsCleared, score, rows, level, gameOver])
```

I would like to give users a choice to continue the game after instantly closing the browser. Thats why in starting game function i am doing:

```
const startGame = () => {
    console.log(loadLocalStorage);
    if (loadLocalStorage){
        setDropTime(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dropTimeStored")));
        setStage(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stageStored")));
        player = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("playerStored"));
        rowsCleared = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rowsClearedStored"));
        setScore(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scoreStored")));
        setRows(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rowsStored")));
        setLevel(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("levelStored")));
        setGameOver(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("gameOverStored")));
    } else {
        localStorage.clear();
        setStage(createStage());
        setDropTime(1000);
        resetPlayer();
        setGameOver(false);
        setScore(0);
        setRows(0);
        setLevel(0);
    }        
}
```

But while the "loadLocalStorage" flag is set to True, which means that the user has clicked the button and is willing to continue the game, nothing has happened. Elements retrieved from local storage are empty, for example the stage has no elements - JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stageStored")) gives me empty stage, with no tetrominoes. Why it is happening? Is closing browser or closing browser's card flushes localStorage? Thanks.

Comment: Ideally not , it is sessionStorage which gets flushed when browser tab is closed. Is the data available in LocalStorage when you reopen the application? Please check the Applications tab in browser.

Comment: During the game, while I check in console JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("stageStored")), I can see tetrominoes in the array. After reloading browser and app, while executing the command above, my stage - array - has every cell empty,  although there were blocks on the board when the browser was closed.

Comment: you have a typo on line 4 of the code you provided:

localStorage.setItem("playerStored", JSON.stringify(stage));

Comment: Can you share how you are initialising the localStorage object in the component ? Also check if the data is there in the browser Storage in the Application tab in developer tools.

Comment: I am not initializing localStorage object. These are two places where I am using it.

Comment: Where are you calling startGame method? in useEffect() hook ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ztmQ81mr - App.js,  https://pastebin.com/6LtLvSU2 - Tetris.js. If you do not mind, I am sharing my code.  @HarmandeepSinghKalsi I am calling start Game method not inside useEffect() hook. They are separated.

Comment: On seeing the code , initially either Welcome Page will be shown or Continue Page. If user clicks on Continue , you are settings the local storage with default values using custom hooks. Hence the data is empty initially . You need to set the data in localStorage during the course of game and not in useEffect hook . In useEffect you should load the data stored in the localStorage.

Comment: But where should I load data to local storage to track every change?

Comment: UseEffect() tracks every change and save it to local storage. In the start game, if there is any game to be continued, load from local storage else starts a new game. Can I invoke UseEffect() in the start method if the condition is satisfied? Instead of using UseEffect, where should I put data into local storage?  I understand. Custom hooks are making element empty, then useEffetc overrides local storage with empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `localStorage.setItem()` calls from useEffect block. For each app refresh, calling `setItem` in useEffect is overriding the actual storage values.

For this to work, set your local storage data whenever you are updating the state. 
For Example, write a common method to update the localStorage data like this :

```
    const updateLocalStorage = (key, value) => {
      localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }
```

Whenever you are updating the state like below, immediately set the localStorage value as well :

```
const dropTime = 1000 / (level + 1) + 200;
setDropTime(dropTime);
updateLocalStorage('dropTimeStored', dropTime);
```

As an example, I have done this change in your code for `dropTime` value in your [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/i54ba1tD) code. You can do the same for other values as well.

Comment: Thank you I understand. Can retrieving data stay in start game function?

Comment: Yeah retrieving data can stay the same as you want to continue the game from previous state.

Comment: I managed to retrieve data from local storage. Stored state is properly loaded but it disappears after a time defined in  useInterval Hook - 1000ms.

Comment: Maybe you clearing the storage somewhere, debug at places where you are clearing the values , you may find the cause.